# The publish operation could not be completed. it cannot be determined if the form template infopath sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, infopath

Please do help me for this issue,

We have changed some columns in list and I tried to customize info-path through ribbon customize button, which opened successfully asking the following alert.
(Even I tried with No, that was saying, which will overwrite the existing columns.)

[image]

I clicked Yes and which opened successfully.

Then I tried to publish, then I got following error,

[image]

Can any one help me for this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below suggestions to solve the issue:

1. Increased the executionTimeout value in web.config and set it to
   3600 seconds.
2. Tried increasing data connection timeout values (to 1 hr) from
   central administrator for InfoPath Forms Services.
3. Checked whether site collection feature “SharePoint Server
   Enterprise Site Collection Features” is activated.
4. Keep the list item around 1500.

Here is an article that list all possible solutions for your reference:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/617d87/resolve-exceptions-occurred-with-existing-infopath-from-in-s/

Comment: Items count is 650 only, and all above points are fine still I am getting the issue. Only thing I have 28 calculated columns in a List.

Comment: Try to reduce the calculated columns when you select data connection and compare the result.